# Wanted an algorithm that pops specfic items on a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-3.x

Could you please help me with this, whatever number the user types, i want this number to be deleted from the list

```
lst = []
while True:

        for i in range(1,21):
                lst.append(i)
#and  now we have a list like this: lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, ...]

        choice = int(raw_input("Select a number: ")
```

now,whatever number the user types,
I want the corresponding number of the list to pop
.The first time its really easy
like: `del lst[choice+1]`
but then the length is "broken"
and the algorithm does not work the way i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `remove`:

```
l = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7]
print "l before removing: {}".format(l)

l.remove(3)
l.remove(6)

print "l after removing: {}".format(l)
```

**output:**

```
l before removing: [1, 3, 5, 6, 7]
l after removing: [1, 5, 7]
```

`remove` throws a `ValueError` if the item is not found, so you'll want to catch that error:

```
choice = 100
try:
    l.remove(choice)
except ValueError:
    print "{} is not in list".format(choice)
```

Comment: But `l.pop(l.index(choice))` is the same as `l.remove(choice)`.